# translate only the first option of the select

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am building an application with AngularJS.

The app is multilanguage. You can change the language from a dropdown (select HTML element).

I have the following select:

```
<select id="filter" class="form-control" ng-model="filter" ng-change="ref()" ng-options="rt.text | translate for rt in rts track by rt.value">
</select>
```

You may see that the `text` has a filter applied, which is `translate`. This is part of Angular Translate module.

My dropdown is populated dynamically from the database and it has an extra option, which is the default option.

What I want is to translate the default option when the language changes and I am not sure how to do it.

The problem with the current solution is that if it has any other option with multilingual translations, they will be translated. I do not want this, all I want is to translate only the default option.

When I add the default option, I set it on `index=0` with a `value='all'` and `text='Show all'`.

The structure of rts:

```
[
 {
  value:'all',
  text: 'Select_all'
 },
 {
  value:'1',
  text: 'option 1'
 },
 {
  value:'2',
  text: 'Option 2'
 }
]
```

Comment: Instead of doing the translate as a filter why not do it in the controller when you get your options?

Comment: I can't do this because I manage the language inside another controller. So when I change the language in the current controller, I don't see a way of translating the value..

Comment: Where does `rts` come from? Can you show an example of how you're getting the options into this directive?

Comment: I added the JSON structure for `rts`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: unfortunately, this will work only if the option value is empty, per ngOptions docs**

Remove the default option from `ng-options`, e.g. using `rts.slice(1)`.

Add it using an `<option>` tag inside the `<select>`.

```
<select ... ng-options="...">
     <option value="">
        {{ rts[0].text | translate }}
     </option>
</select>
```

Then you won't have problem with translating only the default option.

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed example? How do I add the option as the first element of the select using Angular?

Comment: I like this solution! Although I'm still not sure if it will work when the language is changed since there is not watch tied to the translateLanguage.

Comment: @EstebanFelix I would probably prefer you solution myself. Just wanted to add this one as another option.

Comment: I tried your example and it won't work because of `ng-options`. When you change the array, it will automatically replace all the options in the select, even the default one. So in my case it will never appear.

Comment: @tzortzik All right, you are right. You can add one `option` but it needs to have an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just translate only that option on the way from your server? I'm assuming your controller looks something like the following. Also, you'll need to listen to [`$translateChangeSuccess`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service#using-$translate-service_things-to-keep-in-mind) so you know when the language changes:

```
module.controller('RtsCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $translate, rtsService) {
    var translateDefaultOption = function (options) {
        options[0].text = $translate(options[0].text);
        $scope.rts = options;
    };

    var getTranslatedOptions = function () {
        rtsService
                .getOptions()/*<- Might want to cache this or not*/
                .then(translateDefaultOption);
    };

    getTranslatedOptions();

    var cleanUpOnDestroy = $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', getTranslatedOptions);
    $scope.on('$destroy', cleanUpOnDestroy);
});
```

Obviously I don't know how your controller actually works so this is just a crude example.

Comment: If I use this solution, when I change the language from the dropdown, it won't translate the option.

Comment: @tzortzik Is the `translate` filter something your created or something that comes from `angular-translate`? How does the controller that sets the language relate to the controller that handles this `option` directive?

Comment: It comes from `angular-translate`. `MyController` doesn't know anything about `LanguageController` at this moment. All translations from the app are done using `{{'text'"translate}}`.

Comment: @tzortzik Check out my update, you'll need to listen to the `$translateChangeSuccess`.